# Syntax Error in Python while using try-except block with list

Tags: python, list, try-except

I am trying to count number of even or odd numbers from a list in python using try-except block. I am getting the following error:

[image: This is the error I am getting. Please help]

I have mentioned the code below for easy usage:

```
try:
    lst = []
    while True:
        lst.append(int(input())
except:
    even, odd = count(last)
    print("even: {} and odd: {}".format(even,odd))

def count(last):
    even = odd = 0
    for i in last:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even = even + 1
        else:
            odd = odd + 1
    return even, odd
```

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses:  `lst.append(int(input())` needs to be `lst.append(int(input()))`

Comment: Thanks, @TomKarzes for your help. The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis where you take your input.

```
def count(last):
    even = odd = 0
    for i in last:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even = even + 1
        else:
            odd = odd + 1
    return even, odd

try:
    lst = []
    while True:
        lst.append(int(input()))
except:
    even, odd = count(lst)
    print("even: {} and odd: {}".format(even, odd))
```

Comment: even declaring lst in try block will run the program. 
I have attached the correct solution to the problem. Please have a look. thanks!

Comment: An assignment is not a declaration.  Python doesn't really have declarations, aside from scope declarations like `global` and `nonlocal`.  You're mistaking assignments for declarations.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that in Python try block does not create a new scope. I'll edit my answer.